# How to share a Superset Dashboard or Chart?

Tags: dashboard, apache-superset

We connected superset with PostgreSQL and able to make charts and Dashboards. It's easy and really helpful to make dashboards. But now we are looking for the share functionality for dashboards which they also mentioned on their superset introduction pages(on Github and as well as on Airbnb site) that we can create and share the dashboard with others. So how to share dashboard with other users?

Answer (score -2):

Sharing a chart should be easy. You can use the button as shown on the picture:[image]

It is situated on the same page as where you create/edit your chart.
Also to share the chart you'll need to configure a public user and grant him all privileges required to open the chart.

Comment: How to share chart only? No anything else like edit box on the left

Comment: `public user and grant him all privileges required to open the chart` >> can we have a list of these privileges? I'm granting more and more and still not working.